# Android refresh button checking internet connectivity

Tags: android

i'm developing an android project where when i press the refresh button if there is no internet connection then it must show a toast messege.i implemented this if there is no internet connection when the page loads.but how to implement the same code in refresh button?

```
this is my connection class

public class Datacon extends Activity {
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

this is mywebview class

```
public class Mywebpage<Bitmap> extends Activity {
  ProgressBar loadingProgressBar,loadingTitle;
  Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
  ConnectionDetector cd;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final Context context = this;
setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);
AdView ads=(AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adViewer);
AdRequest request=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
ads.loadAd(request);
View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_actionbar, null);
final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 
actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradientwhite));
Button search = (Button) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent inte=new Intent(Mywebpage.this,MainActivity.class);
inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(inte);
    finish();
    }
    })    ;


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String title;
final String url;

if (!Datacon.checkInternetConnection(this)) {

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Check your Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} else {

if (extras != null) {
    title = extras.getString("title");
    url = extras.getString("url");
    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(title);
    final WebView myWebView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); 
    loadingProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); 

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });


Button refresh = (Button) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.but2);
  cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);           
         NetworkInfo netInfo = con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        String status = netInfo.getState().toString();
        if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) {
       myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        } 

        else {
            Context context_new = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context_new, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }


         }
    });

    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: you didn't do anything inside the refresh button for checking internet connection.you just load the url.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "internet available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick doesn't reference the internet check method. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (Datacon.checkInternetConnection(getActivity())) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is getactivity()method here??

Comment: This is the context, you can't use "this" because inside an onClick the context will be for the button.

Comment: *getactivity is used in FRAGMENTS.* he is having an **Activity** . Use it as `Toast.makeText(Datacon.this "no internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Yes please use the appropriate context to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `checkInternetConnection` on the click of `Refresh` button :

```
   Context context= this;
   refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (!checkInternetConnection(context)) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                    else{
                        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
                    }

            }
    });
```

Comment: it is showing error messege "The method checkInternetConnection(Context) in the type Datacon is not applicable for the arguments ()".

Comment: change it to `Datacon.checkInternetConnection(Datacon.this)`

Comment: sorry..it is showing another error No enclosing instance of the type Datacon is accessible in scope..

Comment: Do one thing..take a context in a variable in OnCreate like `Context context = this;` and then replace `Datacon.this` with `this`

Comment: i tried it the nw the error is gone but its not showing the toast messege when there is no internet connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64754/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-thushara-prasad).

Answer (score 0):

Your `refresh` button is already in the activity which holds method for Internet connectivity. So simply call that method in its `onClick` like:

```
refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!checkInternetConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        else{
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The method checkInternetConnection(Context) is undefined for the type

Comment: Show complete code. You are making some minor mistake @Thusharaprasad